# Find if it's possible to make up a integer with some given numbers

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

Question:

Find if its possible to make up a integer (say N) with 21,19 and 37?

```
a. N will be provided as input
b. You can use only these three numbers: 27,19,37
c. Only multiplication, addition, repetition and replacement are allowed
```

For example:

```
Input: 24, Output: not possible
Input: 94, Output: possible - 94 = 19*3 + 37
```

My Queries:

1. Can you please help me in this assignment to show the path of DP / Div & Con / Greedy?
2. Which one shall I choose and why not the others (in this case)?
3. I'd appreciate could you make yourself a little more flexible to explain in terms of DP / Greedy / Div & Con equations and explain your thought process.
    As, for example, in Longest Common Subsequence we use the following:

   ```
   //assuming X[i.....m] and Y[j.....n]    
   LCS(i,j) = {
       0 ,                                 when  i = m or j=n
       Max { LCS(i, j+1) , LCS(i+1, j)  }  when X[i] ≠ Y[j]  
       1+ LCS(i+1,j+1)                     when X[i] == Y[j]
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't get the problem. `19 + 19 - 37 = 1`. You can repeat that pattern to make every number you want (`N = 2 * N * 19 - N * 37`). Can you make the allowed operations explicit?

Comment: @Heuster Subtraction doesn't appear to be allowed (I'm not sure what "repetition" and "replacement" is supposed to mean here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is same as the Knapsack problem with following parameters :-

```
W = Knapsack capacity = N

items = 19 ( N/19 times), 27 (N/27 times), 37 (N/37 times).

Cost & weight of items are same.

Maximize profit. If maximum profit equals N then it is possible to construct N using 19,27,37
```

There is a DP solution of Knapsack problem : -

[Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

**Note:** You should study Knapsack problem by yourself donot end up posting another question for its code.

Comment: Thanks Vikram,  liked it ....waiting for any other different thought process too :)

Comment: @ArnabDutta Another way to do it is Linear Integer Programming where 19*x + 27*y + 37*z = N and x,y,z>=0 . Can be solved using standard solvers. But in any case you will get similar time complexity because the problem is NP Complete

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd thought...:)